# Counting the no of elements in a data structure from the current index from right to left and printing the count for each element

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

Various signal towers are present in a city.Towers are aligned in a straight horizontal line(from left to right) and each tower transmits a signal in the right to left direction.Tower A shall block the signal of Tower B if Tower A is present to the left of Tower B and Tower A is taller than Tower B. So,the range of a signal of a given tower can be defined as :

{(the number of contiguous towers just to the left of the given tower whose height is less than or equal to the height of the given tower) + 1}.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> res;
void recursion(int a[],int x)
{
if (x >= 0)
{// Taking the last element of the array as the max element
    int max = a[x], count = 0;
    for (int i = x; i >= 0; i--)
    {//Comparing the max with all the elements in the array
        if (max >= a[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Pushing the count of the current element in the vector.
    res.push_back(count);
    x = x - 1;
    recursion(a, x);
}
}
    int main() {
int TestCase, n;
cin >> TestCase;
for (int l = 0; l < TestCase; l++)
{
    cin >> n;
    int * arr = new int[n];
    //Getting the elements
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> arr[j];
    }
    recursion(arr, n-1);
    //Iterating through the vector in reverse manner and printing 
            //the result.
    for (auto it = res.rbegin(); it != res.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
return 0;
}
```

First line contains an integer T specifying the number of test cases.

Second line contains an integer n specifying the number of towers.

Third line contains n space separated integers(H[i]) denoting the height 
of each tower.

Print the range of each tower (separated by a space).

**Sample Input**:

```
1
7
100 80 60 70 60 75 85
```

**Sample Output**:

```
1 1 1 2 1 4 6
```

My solution is correct but the time complexity is the issue. Is there any way to reduce time complexity?

Comment: I think your example output is wrong. It should be `1 1 1 2 1 5 6'. Right?

Comment: What is the problem statement?

Comment: What is wrong with the time complexity? What /is/ the time complexity? Why do you think it needs improvement? BTW: The asymptotic complexity of algorithms is language-independent, so C++ code could as well be pseudocode.

Comment: @RobertBaron No and could you please explain why do you think it should be 1 1 1 2 1 5 6 instead of 1 1 1 2 1 5 6? the counting should always start from the current index and it should move from R to L.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt no I just wanted to know whether any better approach to this problem is available or not and I think there is because the test cases are failing.

Comment: @vivek_23 the problem statement is to count the number of elements from right to left starting from the current index and based on  that print the count.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt For each element in the array we are running a for loop and inside the loop we are comparing with all the lelements, so I feel this is time consuming. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looking again, there seems to be something inconsistent in the answers. For answer 4, it is the number of towers the signal goes over while for answer 2 it is not the number of towers the signal goes over (which is 1) but the "distance" to the farthest tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To calculate the range of each tower which emits signals to the left, you need to use a `stack` structure.
- We go from **left to right** in the array and we will store each element in the stack. Now, we insert towers in the stack.
- Whenever we get to the next tower, we keep popping towers from the stack whose height is less than the current tower. Once done, we will insert the current tower in the stack and so on for subsequent towers.
- **Important thing** to note here is that you will need to store the no. of towers beaten by the current tower too when you insert them in the stack.
- Answer for each tower(Except the base case) is no. of towers beaten + 1.
- The integer inside `{}` below is the no. of towers beaten by the current tower.

**Example:**

> ```
> 100 80 60 70 60 75 85
>  ^
> ```

- Stack is empty when we are at `100`, so we insert it into the stack and print answer for it as `1` considering that as the base answer.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0}
> 80 60 70 60 75 85
> ^
> ```

- Now, let's test for `80`. When tower `80` emits signals to the left, we keep pooping all elements from the stack which are less than `80` and stop when we get a block(that is, a tower with same or higher height). In this case, we stop at `100` itself. So, the distance covered by the signal is `1`.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0} 80{0}
> 60 70 60 75 85
> ^
> ```

- Now, the answer for `60` is `1` again.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0} 80{0} 70{1}
> 70 60 75 85
> ^
> ```

- For `70`, signals beat `60` and stop at `80`, so answer for `70` is no. of towers beaten + 1, so 1 + 1 = 2.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0} 80{0} 70{1} 60{0}
> 60 75 85
> ^
> ```

- `60` beats nobody, so 0 + 1 = 1.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0} 80{0} 75{3}
> 75 85
> ^
> ```

- `75` beats `60` and `70`, but we get `3` towers beaten since we add no. of towers beaten by the smaller towers + that tower itself as well. So, to put it in simple words,

60{0} is 1(60 itself) + 0(no. of towers beaten by `60` itself) + 1 (70 itself) + 1(no. of towers beaten by `70` itself) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3. Answer for 75 is 3 + 1 = 4.

> ```
> Current stack: 100{0} 85{5}
> 85
> ^
> ```

- Answer for `85` is 5 + 1 = 6 => 1(of 75) + 3(of 75 beats) + 1(of 80) + 0 (of 80 beats).

Hope this answers your question.